# Unable to receive Push Notification from backend via FCM

Tags: firebase, notifications, swift3, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

quick brief, I have developed an app for iOS and Android, they share the same DB, and I have implemented Firebase on both projects, according to Google Firebase tutorials, but when my backend sends the push notification I receive the notification successfully on Android but nothing appears in my iOS device or console.

Here is my backend code (PHP):

```
    $message = array('message' => 'Blood Donation alert ',
                 'mobile' => $rdmob,
                 'name' => $rdname,
                 'bt' => $rdbt,
                 'rh' => $rdrh,
                 'loclat' =>$rdloclat,
                 'loclon' =>$rdloclon,
                 'locdetails' =>$BD_R_loc_details);

sendMessageThroughGCM($tokens_arr, $message);






function sendMessageThroughGCM($registatoin_ids, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,

    );
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AAAA3n_S2aE:APA91bFpFVn5XbhP_FeXXoZGkG9la94WTMsORZwKrzd-0sNKM8nbjM_E2jMcaAjaubMP11pgby4RFUllVAaUBcmkoOaOw7NG-Xa-JOhfY-UCq829Wa49yxw0IttAnSUge_P4Wmtg");
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode($fields['data']);
 }
```

Backend response:

```
"multicast_id":8083296270394010691,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1487685174974179%af466c60f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1487685175118033%85bd0ba8f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Here is my iOS Appdelegate.swift:

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID

var gAPNS_Token: String?

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //GoogleMaps Setup
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAK0eCZr-V8DxbjjXcpZ549s")
        //GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAK0eCZr-V8DxbFeis")

        //Navigation bar customization
        let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

        navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9999960065, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8692382813, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        // change navigation item title color
        navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]

        return true
    }

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the InstanceID token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print(deviceTokenString)

        gAPNS_Token = deviceTokenString

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                    //Do stuff
                    print("%@", message);
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                //Do stuff
                print("Do stuff")
            }
        }

    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification


        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)


        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                    //Do stuff
                    print("%@", message);
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                //Do stuff
                print("Do stuff")
            }
        }

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

**Notes:** 
 **- I have APNS certificate, and my app obtains an APNS token and FCM token successfully.**

**- iOS receives the notification successfully only if I did it manually, Firebase Console -> Notification -> Send new notification (Targeting iOS App).**

**UPDATE:**

PHP Code update

```
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
   'priority' => 'high',

    );
```

I have assigned priority high to message now, and still unable to receive it on iOS.

Comment: Can you try adding the `priority` parameter with value set to `high` in your payload? Like `'priority' => 'high'`.

Comment: the priority by default is high @AL.

Comment: Err. [*By default, `notification` messages are sent with high priority, and `data` messages are sent with normal priority.*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json). You're using `data` in your payload.

Comment: @AL. check my question update please, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had faced same issue and reason behind that is payload format for iPhone and Android is different.
If payload format doesn't contain "notification" key you will not receive any notification on your iPhone.

Please tell your backend PHP developer to create separate payload format for iOS and Android application.

Other wise create same payload which contains both "notifications" and "data" keys as follows.

{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Push title",
      "body":"Message body"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Nick ",
      "Room" : "Room"
    }
  }
}

You can refer following link for payload format.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: It worked. Notification key was missing. After adding it, it worked like a charm. Thanks.